# AngularJS ng-switch causing templates to momentarily appear

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a single page angular app with an authentication service. The landing page of the app is a form where the user can sign in. There is also a link to a "sign up" page where the user can create an account. These are implemented via the `ng-switch` directive as my authentication service seems to prevent me from redirecting to a new url when the user clicks on "sign up". When the user has signed in, they see a menubar which should only be seen when the user is authenticated. My problem is that when I hit the refresh button while on the landing page, the "sign up" form and the menubar flash in the background of the "sign in" form for a split second. Hope that explanation makes sense, anyone know how to fix it or have a suggestion for a better structure?

Here's my index.html:

```
<html  ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
    <title> My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/passwordvalidation.css">
     <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-switch on="view.controller">

    <div ng-switch-default ng-controller="UserCtrl">

        <div ng-show="!isAuthenticated">
            <form class = "form-signin">

//Sign In Form code here

                        <button class = "btn btn-primary" ng-click="signIn()">Sign In</button>

//This button performs the ng-switch based on the controller name
                        <button class = "btn btn-default" ng-click= "view.controller = 'UserNewCtrl'" >Register</button>

                    </div> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
<!--This part of index.html is only shown when a user has been authenticated -->


        <div ng-show="isAuthenticated">
//MenuBar Code here

            </div>

<!--This is where partials will be loaded depending on menu item selection-->
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <div ng-view></div>

            </div>

        </div>


    </div>


<!--Start of sign up form-->

    <div ng-switch-when="UserNewCtrl" >
        <div ng-controller = "UserNewCtrl" >
            <div ng-show="!isAuthenticated">

//Sign Up Form Code here

               </div>
            </div>    
        </div>

    <!--End of Sign Up Form-->



    <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-utils.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And my MainCtrl which is supposed to control the whole page, and sets the default Controller to the one which handles signing in so that the sign in form is the first thing you land on, if it helps:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.view={
      controller: 'UserCtrl'
    }; 

  })
```

Comment: Take a look at the `ng-cloak` attribute [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) issue. The form flashes because it appears in the default state of your page before AngularJS has finished bootstrapping.

Check out [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) or consider moving your form into an element directive that is rendered conditionally.

Comment: Any advice on how to use ngCloak? The documentation is pretty sparse.

Comment: Got it to work and fixed the problem perfectly, thanks!